# TargetException thrown while using reflection to add an event handler

Tags: .net, reflection, asynchronous, delegates, backgroundworker

I want to invoke a BackgroundWorker thread when a WebClient object calls back.

The method which I target to run on this BackgroundWorker is not fixed so I need to programmatically target a specified method.

To achieve this:
One of the properties on the event args object passed to the WebClient details which method should be obtained (e.UserState.ToString()). This method *is* being obtained as expected.

What I then hope to do is add this obtained method as a delegate on the BackgroundWorker.DoWork event.

```
// this line gets the targeted delegate method from the method name
var method = GetType().GetMethod(e.UserState.ToString(), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (method != null)
{
    // get the DoWork delegate on the BackgroundWorker object
    var eventDoWork = _bw.GetType().GetEvent("DoWork", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var tDelegate = eventDoWork.EventHandlerType;
    var d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(tDelegate, this, method);

    // add the targeted method as a handler for the DoWork event
    var addHandler = eventDoWork.GetAddMethod(false);
    Object[] addHandlerArgs = { d };
    addHandler.Invoke(this, addHandlerArgs);

    // now invoke the targeted method on the BackgroundWorker thread
    if (_bw.IsBusy != true)
    {
        _bw.RunWorkerAsync(e);
    }
}
```

For some reason a TargetException is thrown on the line

```
addHandler.Invoke(this, addHandlerArgs);
```

The exception message is

> Object does not match target type.

The signature of the method which I'm building the code around is

```
private void GotQueueAsync(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

This matches the signature for a BackgroundWorker.DoWork event handler.

Can anyone explain to me what I've done wrong or why I'm unable to programmatically add this handler method.

[In case it matters, this is a WP7 app.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing `this` incorrectly:

```
addHandler.Invoke(this, addHandlerArgs);
```

The object with the event is not `this` (although `this` has the handler) - it should be `_bw`:

```
addHandler.Invoke(_bw, addHandlerArgs);
```

More simply, though:

```
var d = (DoWorkEventHandler)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(DoWorkEventHandler), this, method);
_bw.DoWork += d;
```

Or at least use `EventInfo.AddEventHandler`.

Comment: Yes, both suggestions work perfectly. That's saved me a lot of head-scratching. Thanks.